# Unauthenticated Message In Sanctum

Tags: laravel, laravel-sanctum

I have read through just about every Stack thread about this but am still getting nowhere.  Using fresh install of Laravel 9.48.0.

cors.php:

```
   'paths' => ['api/*', 'sanctum/csrf-cookie'],

    'allowed_methods' => ['*'],

    'allowed_origins' => ['*'],

    'allowed_origins_patterns' => [],

    'allowed_headers' => ['*'],

    'exposed_headers' => [],

    'max_age' => 0,

    'supports_credentials' => true,
```

.htaccess (using Apache in Homestead)

```
   # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
```

.env:

```
SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS="data-gateway.com,localhost,127.0.0.1,192.168.56.56"
SESSION_DOMAIN=data-gateway.com
```

api.php (routes)

```
Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});
```

Kernel.php

```
class Kernel extends HttpKernel
{
    /**
     * The application's global HTTP middleware stack.
     *
     * These middleware are run during every request to your application.
     *
     * @var array<int, class-string|string>
     */
    protected $middleware = [
        // \App\Http\Middleware\TrustHosts::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies::class,
        \Illuminate\Http\Middleware\HandleCors::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class,
    ];

    /**
     * The application's route middleware groups.
     *
     * @var array<string, array<int, class-string|string>>
     */
    protected $middlewareGroups = [

        'api' => [
            \Laravel\Sanctum\Http\Middleware\EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful::class,
            'throttle:api',
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        ],
    ];

    /**
     * The application's route middleware.
     *
     * These middleware may be assigned to groups or used individually.
     *
     * @var array<string, class-string|string>
     */
    protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
        'auth.session' => \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
        'cache.headers' => \Illuminate\Http\Middleware\SetCacheHeaders::class,
        'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
        'signed' => \App\Http\Middleware\ValidateSignature::class,
        'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
        'verified' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\EnsureEmailIsVerified::class,
        'abilities' => \Laravel\Sanctum\Http\Middleware\CheckAbilities::class,
        'ability' => \Laravel\Sanctum\Http\Middleware\CheckForAnyAbility::class,
    ];
}
```

Sanctum.php

```
return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Stateful Domains
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Requests from the following domains / hosts will receive stateful API
    | authentication cookies. Typically, these should include your local
    | and production domains which access your API via a frontend SPA.
    |
    */

    'stateful' => explode(',', env('SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS', sprintf(
        '%s%s',
        'localhost,localhost:3000,127.0.0.1,127.0.0.1:8000,data-gateway.com,::1',
        Sanctum::currentApplicationUrlWithPort()
    ))),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Sanctum Guards
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This array contains the authentication guards that will be checked when
    | Sanctum is trying to authenticate a request. If none of these guards
    | are able to authenticate the request, Sanctum will use the bearer
    | token that's present on an incoming request for authentication.
    |
    */

    'guard' => ['web'],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Expiration Minutes
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This value controls the number of minutes until an issued token will be
    | considered expired. If this value is null, personal access tokens do
    | not expire. This won't tweak the lifetime of first-party sessions.
    |
    */

    'expiration' => null,

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Sanctum Middleware
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | When authenticating your first-party SPA with Sanctum you may need to
    | customize some of the middleware Sanctum uses while processing the
    | request. You may change the middleware listed below as required.
    |
    */

    'middleware' => [
       // 'verify_csrf_token' => App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
        'encrypt_cookies' => App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
    ],

];
```

But no matter what, I get the Unauthenticated message:

[image]

Here is the CURL command:

[image]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to add "Bearer " to the Authorization value

[image]

Comment: If you want, you can accept your own answer